# jQuery Scroll effect not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I tried my hand at creating a button on my page that animates and scrolls you back to the top of the page. I created a class called upArrow and added it to the button that is supposed to fire the jQuery function. However when I click nothing fires and I am not sure why. Here is the site and my code:

https://jorgeg1105.github.io/JG-Photography/

```js
//When the page loads, Fade in all divs with class hidden.
//Then Remove hidden class.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.hidden').fadeIn(2000).removeClass('hidden');
});

//Fade In all h3 with class hidden.
//Remove hidden class.
$('h3.hidden').fadeIn(3000).removeClass('hidden');

//Image Filter
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#mainnav ul li a").click(function (){
  var category = $(this).attr("class");

  if (category == "all" ){
   $("#imgcontainer img").addClass("hidden");
   setTimeout(function (){
    $("#imgcontainer img").removeClass("hidden");
   });
  }
  else {
   $("#imgcontainer img").addClass("hidden");
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("."+category).removeClass("hidden");
   });
  }
 });
});


//When burger is clicked. Mobile nav and mainnav are toggled.
$(".burger").on("click", function (){
 $("#mainnav").toggleClass("hidden");
 $(".mobilenav").toggleClass("hidden");
});

//When Arrow is clicked page scrolls to the top of the screen.
$('.upArrow').click(function(){
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
 return false;
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

#container {
 flex: 1 0 0;
 overflow-y: auto;
}


/*------------------------Classes to be added to the current active link on a page----------*/
.active {
 color: #766E6B;
}


/*--------------Side Navigation Styles--------------------*/
#sidenav {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 width: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 border-right: 6px solid #766E6B;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

#sidenav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
   justify-content: center;
}

#sidenav ul li:first-child {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
#sidenav ul li:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
  }

#sidenav a {
 padding: 20px;
 display: block;
}

#sidenav a:visited {
 color: white;
}

#sidenav a:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}



/*-------------Header Styles-------------------------------*/
header {
 padding: 40px 30px;
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
}

header h1, h3 {
 font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}

header h1 {
 font-size: 90px;
}

header h3 {
 font-size: 40px;
}

header a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 padding: 0 0 12px 0;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}

header a:hover {
 transition: color 1s;
 color: #766E6B;
}


.smalltxt {
 font-size: 12px;
}

.topnavitems {
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
}

/*------------------Main Navigation-----------------------*/

#mainnav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: black;
}


#mainnav li {
 margin-right: 5px;

}

#mainnav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#mainnav a:hover {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: grey;
}

/*--------------------ImgContainer Area------------------------*/

#imgcontainer {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
}

#imgcontainer img {
 flex: 1;
 width: 40vh;
 padding: 10px;
}

#imgcontainer img:hover {
 border: 2px solid black;
}
/*-----------------------Footer Styles---------------------*/

footer {
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-top: 1px solid grey;

}

footer ul {
 justify-content: center;
}

footer li {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.developer {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

/*-------------------Js Fade In class-------------------*/
.hidden {
 display: none !important;
}

/*-------------------Flexbox-----------------------*/
.col {
 flex: 1;
}

.row {
 display: flex;
}

/*----------------------Mobile Navigation------------------------*/

.mobilenav {
 background-color: black;
 justify-content: center;
 display: none;
}

.mobilenav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 margin: 0;
}

.mobilenav li {
 margin-right: 10px;

}

.mobilenav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 20px;
}

.mobilenav a:hover {
 background-color: grey;
}

.burger {
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 display: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.burger i {
 color: white;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

/*-----------------Mobile Footer------------------------------*/
.mobilefooter {
 display: none;
}

.mobilefooter a {
 color: black;
}

/*-----------Media Queries----------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
 #sidenav {
  display: none;
 }

 nav.mobilenav.row {

  display: none;
 }

 .mobilefooter {
  display: flex;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 930px){
 #imgcontainer img {
  width: 80vh;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
 header a {
  display: none;
 }

 .mobilenav {
  display: flex;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){

 header h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
 }

 header h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
 }

 #imgcontainer img {
  width: 95%;
 }

 #mainnav {
  display: block;
 }

 #mainnav ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
 }

 #mainnav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
 }

 .mobilenav {
  display: block;
 }

 .mobilenav ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;

 }

 .mobilenav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
 }

 .burger {
  display: block;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>| J&amp;D |</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!--Custom CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/styles.css">
 <!--Google Fonts-->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400i|Tangerine:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <nav id="sidenav" class="row">
  <ul class>
   <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="upArrow"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
  <div id="container">
   <span class="burger"><a href="#" class="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
   <nav class="mobilenav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Questions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <header>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="index.html">
         <strong class="active">Gallery</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Our Work</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>About</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">D&amp;J Photography</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Questions</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Facts</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <h1>D&amp;J Photography</h1>
     <h3 class="hidden"><em>"Explore. Create. Inspire."</em></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Rates</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Your Investment</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Contact</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Get In Touch</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <span class="burger"><a href="#" class="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
    <nav id="mainnav">
   <ul class="row">
    <li><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="food">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="people">People</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="landmark">Landmarks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nature">Nature</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sneakers">Sneakers</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="imgcontainer">
   <a href="Images/Food/FriedChicken.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/FriedChicken.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/IcyMountains.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/IcyMountains.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/EiffelTower.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/EiffelTower.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/Girl.jpg"><img src="Images/People/GuyInTrees.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/GoldAndWhite.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/GoldAndWhite.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/ExoticDish.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/ExoticDish.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/VastLandscape.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/VastLandscape.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/LondonBridge.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/LondonBridge.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/GuyWithCap.jpg"><img src="Images/People/GuyWithCap.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Nike.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Nike.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/ShrimpRice.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/ShrimpRice.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/VeryGreenForest.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/VeryGreenForest.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/RomanColosseum.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/RomanColosseum.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/OlderMan.jpg"><img src="Images/People/OlderMan.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Vans.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Vans.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Yeezy.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Yeezy.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/SteakTacos.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/SteakTacos.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/MistyForest.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/MistyForest.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/GermanyCastle.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/GermanyCastle.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/LittleGirl.jpg"><img src="Images/People/LittleGirl.jpg" class="people"></a>
  </div>
  <footer>
   <ul class="row">
    <li><p class="smalltxt">J&amp;G Photography all rights reserved &copy; 2017</p></li>
    <li><p class="smalltxt">Designed and Developed by <strong><a href="http://jorgegoris.com/" class="developer">Jorge Goris</a></strong></p></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="mobilefooter row">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </footer>
 </div>
 <!--jQuery-->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <!--Font Awesome-->
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d579f311e9.js"></script>
   <!--Custom Js-->
   <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to disable the eventDefault associated to your arrow-up link. The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening, which in our case, means it prevents a link from following the '#' URL.

```
    $('#back-to-top').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 700);
```

Have a look to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/LaurMe/rf7uf569/2/) Fiddle I made as an example.

Hope this could help,
Laura.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! @Laura. I tried implementing this into my code but it just disabled all my JS for some reason. Any particular reason why that might be happening?

Comment: Uhmmm...it has disabled all your JS for that functionality or none of the JS you wrote seems to be working anymore?

Comment: Yeah none of the JS works when I plug that piece of code in.

Comment: Cloning your project and adding that piece of code it did not give me any problems (e.g. the hamburger is fine anyway) indeed, it works properly. It is definitively something into your lateral bar style that is producing some conflict with the functionality.
Have a look and let me know :)

Comment: Weird. I cleaned up my jQuery and added it all under the same document.ready() function. Hamburger and fade functions still work. Only the scroll is giving me issues. I also copied the above code line for line and nothing.

Comment: That's strange. By the way, the proof that I made this morning with was a new project using the HTML + JS you made (with my small scrollTop addiction) and the CSS in the fiddle posted in the answer above and everything worked perfectly (of course in that way it is a mess). That's why I supposed the problem is some conflict on your CSS....

Comment: Alright I'll play with it some more. Thanks so much for your help!